# How to escape json strings in freemarker

Tags: java, json, spring, escaping, freemarker

We are building a restful api using Spring MVC and freemarker as the templating language. We have chosen to build json responses in the freemarker

Example freemarker.ftl:

```
{
"field1" : "${response.value1}",
"field2" : "${response.value2}"
}
```

We get a problem when the strings in the values contain quotation marks (or any of the other characters in the JSON syntax).

The question: **How can I escape these strings using freemarker?**

We have looked at `?xml` or `?html` but they do not cover all relevant characters (such as `\`).

**EDIT:** `?js_string` will escape the string to comform with JavaScript. And since JSON is based on JavaScript (JavaScript Object Notation), it will work.

**EDIT2:** In case a single-quote pops up, `?js_string` will escape it which again leads to invalid JSON. The hotfix for it is:

```
${variable?js_string?replace("\\'", "\'")}
```

and if you really want to be picky:

```
${variable?js_string?replace("\\'", "\'")?replace("\\>",">")}
```

Alternatively if you use Spring: http://www.springsurf.org/sites/1.0.0.M3/spring-webscripts/spring-webscripts-documentation/reference/html-single/index.html#js-api-index-org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.json.jsonutils

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're looking for the `?js_string` operator.

```
{
"field1" : "${response.value1?js_string}",
"field2" : "${response.value2?js_string}"
}
```

That will take care of escaping quotes, backslashes, et. al in order to make your JS happy.

**Edit**: I just saw that they introduced a `?json_string` operator in Freemarker 2.3.19.  See [here](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_json_string) for exactly how it works.  And there was much rejoicing...

Comment: Whats the advantage to ?js_string over ?j_string in this case?

Comment: @Skurpi The advantage is that `js_string` does the necessary escaping while `j_string` does not.

Comment: @Waldheinz @stevevls It seems it does not work entirely.

See the following example: 
{ "companyName" : "Rehabshopen AB, Göran Sjödén\'s" , "companyText" : "Vi säljer träning, sjukvård, hygienartiklar & ortoser. Uthyrning och försäljning av rullstolar &..." }
If you run it through a validator it will fail, and the string has been ?js_string escaped.

http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#jsonformatter

Comment: @Skurpi I see...it doesn't like the escaped single quote.  Try this to get rid of the backslashes on the single quote : `${variable?js_string?replace('\\'', '\'')}`

Comment: It seems risky to try to fix individual problems like that. I'd prefer an "automated" way to handle this, since there might be some other characters that it'll escape that might fail.

Comment: @stevevls it should be: ${variable?js_string?replace("\\'", "\'")} But excellent!

Comment: @Skurpi Agreed that a built-in would be the best way to go.  Hopefully they'll put one in the next version of Freemarker!

Answer (score 2):

Use a [FreeMarker macro](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_directive_macro.html) to combine all of the answers above, while making the template more readable and maintainable:

```
<#macro json_string string>${string?js_string?replace("\\'", "\'")?replace("\\>", ">")}</#macro>
{
"field1" : "<@json_string "${response.value1}"/>",
"field2" : "<@json_string "${response.value2}"/>"
}
```

If you want to reuse the macro in multiple templates, put it in its own file and [include the file](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_directive_include.html) instead of duplicating the macro:

```
<#include "/path/to/macro.ftl">
```

Comment: This is actually what we did, but we put some extra functionality in it which we had use for:
<#macro hazStringContent content>
 <#if content?has_content && content != "">"${content?js_string?replace("\\'", "\'")?replace("\\>",">")}"<#else>null</#if>
</#macro>

Answer (score 0):

Starting from FreeMarker 2.3.32, it's much easier, as `?c` now quotes strings:

```
{
"field1" : ${response.value1?c},
"field2" : ${response.value2?c}
}
```

Note that there are no quotes around the `${...}`! That's the point; the `?c` puts them there if the value is a string (as opposed to a number or a boolean, which are formatted without adding quotation marks).

Before 2.3.32 the above terminates with error, as string input wasn't allowed by `?c`, only numbers and booleans.

Starting from 2.3.32, instead of `?c`, you can also use `?cn`, which stands for "?c nullable". Then if the value is missing/`null`, it will output `null`, without the quotes. So you don't have to complicate the template with printing quotes conditionally either.

Also, It's a good idea to set the `c_format` setting to `"JSON"`, or `"JavaScript or JSON"`. (Or, if you set the `incompatible_improvements` configuration setting to 2.3.32 or higher anyway, the last will be the default.)

Comment: i'm not able to use `?cn` in 2.3.32 java client.
Its saying unrecognized built-in

Comment: @KrittamKothari `?cn` is definitely supported in 2.3.32. What does `${.version}` say?

Comment: you're right my dependencies were messed up; somehow i was using 2.3.31. Its working once i fixed dependencies